# Using JFileChooser to insert images into mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, blob, jfilechooser

I'm trying to store images into mysql database through a jfilechooser. I already created a column of longblob datatype in mysql using phpmyadmin. How can i insert an image into mysql database from JFileChooser?

Comment: Some kind of reader and a [`blob`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html).

Comment: `JFileChooser` will give you `File` reference, you can open an `InputStream` to it and write it to a blob.  I'd do some more research on how to insert a file into a database as this seems to be more of your problem